# What does this mean in Xcode?

Tags: ios

What does this mean?

From Xcode:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/AVKit.framework/AVKit
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/50BC86A1-5C48-444F-A41A-6AB88D43D3B0/AviaryDemo-iOS.app/AviaryDemo-iOS
  Reason: image not found
```

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do. Post some code where this error is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that your *code* imports the AVKit headers, but the AVKit framework *itself* has not been linked into your target.

This problem can arise when using `#import <...>` syntax, and the solution would then require an extra step (namely, add AVKit manually to the linked frameworks in your target's build phases). But it cannot arise when using `@import` syntax, because what is imported is then a module, and you get auto-linking of modules by default. This is one of the reasons modules are Cool (technical programming term).